# Powershell Like operator invokes REST error

Tags: powershell

I am working on a custom PoweShell module picked up from the internet for our BI application.

My question is rather simple, the code below does not work:

```
Get-QlikDataConnection -filter "name -like 'Data*'"
```

And throws an error like:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Qlik-Cli\1.13\functions\core.ps1:32 char:15
+ ...   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $method -Uri $path @params -Web ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

However the code below works fine and shows me the correct output:

```
Get-QlikDataConnection -filter "name eq 'DataPrepAppCache'"
```

Am I doing something wrong or do some modules not understand a few operators?

Comment: I am not familiar with that cmdlet. Does `-match` work?

Comment: An obvious difference is that `-like` has a hyphen at the start, whereas `eq` does not. Should it be `like`?

Comment: _custom PoweShell module picked up from the internet_. [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Qlik-Admin-Utils/3.2.5.2/Content/Get-QlikDataConnection.ps1)? Where did you find it? Did it come with documentation? If its custom it does not need to conform to any standard other than its own. You should be able to debug this as well by seeing how the filter is parsed.

Comment: If it is a custom module, is it possible they implemented their own filter syntax?  You may need to reach out to the provider.

Comment: Sorry for the dealyed reply. Here is where I picked up the custom module from: https://github.com/ahaydon/Qlik-Cli

Comment: Well eq works.. I was hoping -like works too

Comment: like with hyphen or without hyphen does not work.. I think eq works with and without hyphen too right?

Comment: Can some custom modules block a few commands.. Or not accept a few commands. I thought all modules accept standard commands (like in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look at [the source of the module you're using, Qlik-Admin-Utils](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Qlik-Admin-Utils/3.2.5.1), I would not use the `-filter` param, as the input you specify there gets processed by this block within the `Invoke-QlikGet` cmdlet:

```
  If( $filter ) {
      If( $path.contains("?") ) {
        $path += "&filter=$filter"
      } else {
        $path += "?filter=$filter"
      }
    }
```

This script appends your filter as a query parameter in the URL, and it doesn't support regular PowerShell formatting, but sends the filter over to qLik's REST API.

If I were writing this, I'd ignore their filtering and do the following:

```
$Connections = Get-QlikDataConnection 
$DataConnection = $Connections | Where name -like "Data*"
```

This is more likely to just work with less fiddling.

However, if you want to use Qlik's Filter support, [I found this so you can read up on the syntax of it here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/1.0/Subsystems/Qlik_Sense_Repository_Service_API/Content/QRS%20API/Repository_REST_API_Filtering.htm).

It looks like they **do offer** a filter of their own which might help, it's the `Starts With` filter, defined as `SW`, for a syntax of `Name sw 'Data'`.  You might try this and see if it works instead.

```
Get-QlikDataConnection -filter "name sw 'Data'"
```

Comment: Well that was insanely quick. How did you manage to find all this? Can you please enlighten? I am a beginner and sometimes am lost.

Comment: Happy to help.  I went to the gallery and downloaded that module then opened it in VSCode.  I looked at the command you were calling by opening it's `.ps1` file from VSCode.  Then I scrolled down to the 'payload' of the file to see that it passes input off to a cmdlet called `Invoke-QlikGet`.  I wanted to know how that worked so I highlghted the command name and hit `F12` to go to the definition, and repeated the process till I figured it out.  This all comes with time, you're on the right path.